# How to make Material UI's styled() svg icon accept svg icon as a react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have the following code that is currently working, but the issue is that I am using "any" as the type for props. Before refactoring to MUI v5, there was no issue with this approach. using the mui v4 makeStyles

```js
// SVG Icons components import 
import { ReactComponent as AppLogo } from '../../../icons/appLogo.svg';




// Styled Mui Component 
export const StyledLogo = styled(SvgIcon)<any>(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  fill: theme.palette.primary.main,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  borderRadius: 10,
  margin: 5,
  verticalAlign: 'middle',
}));



<StyledLogo component={AppLogo} viewBox='0 0 700 700' />
```

so when i remove any , the component props shows any error telling

> Type '{ component: FunctionComponent<SVGProps & { title?: string | undefined; }>; viewBox: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial | undefined; color?: OverridableStringUnion<"inherit" | ... 7 more ... | "warning", SvgIconPropsColorOverrides> | undefined; ... 6 more ...; viewBox?: string | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...> & MUIStyledCommonProps<...> & { ...; }'.
> Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial | undefined; color?: OverridableStringUnion<"inherit" | ... 7 more ... | "warning", SvgIconPropsColorOverrides> | undefined; ... 6 more ...; viewBox?: string | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...> & MUIStyledCommonProps<...> & { ...; }'.ts(2322)
> (property) component: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps & {
> title?: string | undefined;

any idea how to make this compatible... and I don't want to use any the current type showing on the icon import :

> const AppLogo: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps & {
> title?: string | undefined;
> }>

Comment: What is the `SvgIcon`?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me like this:

```
export const StyledLogo = styled(SvgIcon)<{component?: any}>(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  fill: theme.palette.primary.main,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  borderRadius: 10,
  margin: 5,
  verticalAlign: 'middle',
}));
```

Comment: it won’t scale … it needs to be reusable.

Comment: Updated answer for reuse option

Comment: Any is not good there must be a type.